# Comment pagination - How to show determined number of comments on the first page?

Tags: comments, pagination

I set 10 comments for every page. If I have 20 comments, it shows 10-10 on the first and last page.

However if I have 11 comments, it shows 1 comment on the first page.

How to display 10 comments on the first page whether I have 20 or 11 comments as total?

Note: New (last) comments show first.

Comment: Where or how are your setting to 10 comments, here wp-admin/options-discussion.php?

Comment: Hi. Yes, here in Discussion options.

Comment: You theme comments.php should be broken, it shouldn't happen

Comment: Forget to add: I set new comments show first.